# Where is Titan Souls's save file?

Tags: windows-7, titan-souls

I want to copy [Titan Souls](http://store.steampowered.com/app/297130/) to a pc, which doesn't have internet (but have the same OS). I copied the game folder from Program Files, and wanted to copy save folder from c:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\ but couldn't find it there.

The game works, and even has the save slot, but when I load the save slot I start from the very begging. Also that save slot says "2 bosses killed", while the only save slot on the main PC said "6 bosses killed". This is strage, but clearly I still need to find the save file. Where it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the game folder in `\data\SAVE\`.

[Source](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Titan_Souls#Configuration_file.28s.29_location)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but this is definetly not the case for me. There is a folder like this, but it is not updated when I progress in the game, nor content, nor the time stamp.

Comment: @klm123: An easy way to find out, which I use all the time, is to use the Everything search program which is at https://www.voidtools.com/ - the fact that Googling "everything" gives this as the first hit says something. It indexes the names of the files and folders on your disks - which takes only a few seconds even if it's millions of files - and anything you type in it will *instantly* give you a list of results. Since you already know what file to look for, enter its name, sort by change-date. :)

Comment: @DreamspacePresident, I don't know what file to look for. In \data\SAVE\ there is file 0.txt, i've searched for it, and there is no other file with this name on my computer. The same for "Titan" keyword - it gives only the folder in the Program Files.

Comment: I've tried to search by "date changed" and found nothing. I guess something is very wrong with my system. So I just accept this answer.

Comment: @klm123: Are you sure that progress isn't saved to `0.txt` file? My file has values such as <Deaths count="8" /> and `<SavePoint id="floor1_spawn" />`.

Comment: @user598527, yes, 0.txt says 2 kills, game says 6 kills. And file is 2 months old.

Comment: @klm123: Try using Search Everything linked above to confirm there are no other 0.txt files on your hard drive. Search for 1-9`.txt` too, assuming that's the naming scheme the game uses. Where have you installed the game? Do you have several Steam game folder locations? Lastly, consider disabling Steam cloud for the game as it isn't supported according to the game's store page, but still enabled. I doubt I can help any further.

Comment: @DreamspacePresident: They are config files, not save files, but I would certainly backup them as well.